PBI : Measure based on 2 columns from 2 different tables
I have a 2 tables :
1 Fact table
1 Dimension table
for certain entries in my fact table, I can have a comment and in this case I would like to display it instead of displaying the dimension table value. Of course in an unique column in the visual table
I guess  I need to create a Measure but I can't seem to use text values.
Is this the right method and how do I go about it?

Thanks

If you want to calculate this for each row of your fact table, it might be easier to add a calculated column to the fact table rather than use a measure.
Here's a basic expression you could use in a calculated column in the fact table (it assumes that there's a many-to-one relationship between the fact table and dimension table):
What I want Calculated Column = IF(
    ISBLANK('FACT table'[Comment]),
    RELATED('Dim table'[Description]),
    'FACT table'[Comment]
)

This gives me the following results:

